Why is "וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ" not a standalone verse and preceded by "לֹא־תִקֹּם וְלֹא־תִטֹּר"?
In Lev 19.18: "לֹא־תִקֹּם וְלֹא־תִטֹּר ... וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ",

Why "love thy fellow" is an "aftermath", an "elaboration" on "don't avenge or hold grudges"?
Why isn't it the other way around: "Love thy fellow; don't avenge or hold grudges"?
Why isn't it a standalone verse altogether?

